# remove selected items from shopping cart in magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

```
<script>
    function getValueUsingClass(){
       /* declare an checkbox array */
       var chkArray = [];

       /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
       $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
           chkArray.push($(this).val());
       });

       /* we join the array separated by the comma */
       var selected;
       selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

       /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
       if(selected.length > 1){
          alert("You have selected " + selected);   
       }else{
          alert("Please at least one of the checkbox"); 
       }
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Remove Selected" id="buttonClass">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>">
```

I have a shopping card with multiple items in it.
How do i delete the selected items from my shopping card?

[image]

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi I think he wants to delete the selected items from his shopping card.     

Yogesh, Please provide some code that u'r using. We are not here to write the whole application for you, but to help you with the things u'r stuck on. 
So provide the code, and explain what's not working.

Comment: i get item ids but i can't removed the selected items in cart. Please provide multiple delete code.

Answer (score 0):

> [image]Why don't you use this plugin
>   [Multiple Items Delete (Shopping Cart)](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-items-delete-shopping-cart.html)

Comment: now i'm using this plugin but i get some error in shopping cart page

Comment: please see this link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk3oa.png]  Checkbox not showing in delete column

Comment: I think this might be a style issue. please inspect that area and check for checkbox

Comment: no its not a style issue. checkbox not showing in delete column. but no issues comes for inspect and console area also

Comment: Then make sure there is no extension conflict. Go through the module and try to debug. Are u sure that there is no style ovelap?? hidden checkbox?? check code thoroughly..

Comment: `<?php $_isMultiDelete = 0; $_isMultiDelete = Mage::getStoreConfig('multicartdelete/general/enabled'); 
var_dump($_isMultiDelete); ?>
        <?php if($_isMultiDelete){ ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="massCartDelete[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"  title="Select & Update Shopping Cart to remove Item" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: inherit; margin-right: 5px;"/>
        <?php } ?>`